# the web page is temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to another address. ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

Tags: php, rss, feed

I'm trying to get an RSS feed, I remove all stopwords, stemm... but it works sometimes. I do not know what is happening. Could anyone see my code and tell me where is the error?. Please

functions.php

```
<?php
include ("stemm_es.php");

function quitarAcento($incoming_string){
    $tofind = "ÀÁÂÄÅàáâäÒÓÔÖòóôöÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ";
    $replac = "AAAAAaaaaOOOOooooEEEEeeeeCcIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuyNn";
    return utf8_encode(strtr(utf8_decode($incoming_string), 
                             utf8_decode($tofind),
                             $replac));
}

function limpiar($String){
    $String = str_replace(array('á','à','â','ã','ª','ä'),"a",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Á','À','Â','Ã','Ä'),"A",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Í','Ì','Î','Ï'),"I",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('í','ì','î','ï'),"i",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('é','è','ê','ë'),"e",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('É','È','Ê','Ë'),"E",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('ó','ò','ô','õ','ö','º'),"o",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Ó','Ò','Ô','Õ','Ö'),"O",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('ú','ù','û','ü'),"u",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Ú','Ù','Û','Ü'),"U",$String);
    $String = str_replace(array('[','^','´','`','¨','~',']','"',"'",'(',')','{','}',',','.',':',';','%','-',
                                '#','@','|','!','·','$','&','/','?','¡','¿','+', '”', '“', '’', '‘'),"",$String);
    $String = str_replace("ç","c",$String);
    $String = str_replace("Ç","C",$String);
    $String = str_replace("ñ","n",$String);
    $String = str_replace("Ñ","N",$String);
    $String = str_replace("Ý","Y",$String);
    $String = str_replace("ý","y",$String);

    $String = str_replace("&aacute;","a",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&Aacute;","A",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&eacute;","e",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&Eacute;","E",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&iacute;","i",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&Iacute;","I",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&oacute;","o",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&Oacute;","O",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&uacute;","u",$String);
    $String = str_replace("&Uacute;","U",$String);
    return $String;
}

function getFeed($feed_url) {
    $x = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($feed_url));

    $stopwords = file_get_contents('stopword.txt');
    $stopwords = explode(" ", $stopwords);
    $t=0;
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry){
        $t++;
        $title = trim( strip_tags( mb_strtolower( limpiar($entry->title) ) ) );
        $description = trim( strip_tags( mb_strtolower( limpiar($entry->description) ) ) );
        $title = explode(" ", $title);

        $description = explode(" ", $description);

        for($j = 0; $j < count($title); $j++){
            if($title[$j] != ""){

                for($i = 0; $i < count($stopwords); $i++){
                    if($stopwords[$i] != ""){
                        $title[$j] = preg_replace("/\b$stopwords[$i]\b/i", " ", $title[$j]);
                        $title[$j] = stemm_es::stemm($title[$j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for($j = 0; $j < count($description); $j++){
            if($description[$j] != ""){

                for($i = 0; $i < count($stopwords); $i++){
                    if($stopwords[$i] != ""){
                        $description[$j] = preg_replace("/\b$stopwords[$i]\b/i", " ", $description[$j]);
                        $description[$j] = stemm_es::stemm($description[$j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($title);
        print_r($description);
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Inicio | Investigador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require "functions.php"; ?>
    <?php
    $feed = "http://ep00.epimg.net/rss/ccaa/valencia.xml";
    if ($feed != "") {
        getFeed(feed);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening, what errors you get etc etc

Answer (score 1):

We've had this issue arise for some users with a recent release. Not sure if it is us or timing with Chrome .

It is only affecting some users, and only in Chrome, and clearing cache has helped most users but not all.

Still searching for a definitely solution to it.

EDIT:

After a looooong time I actually resolved it for me by updating the session config settings in CodeIgniter.

I had to update:

```
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
```

to:

```
     $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
```

What was happening was on first login, it would work fine, but the second login was getting some sort of conflict with the cookie.

I didn't find out exactly what the issue was, but this seems to be a Chrome based bug a few people have had over the years, but there's not much around on it.